# java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType is returning wrong value

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have an simple interface within an another interface and trying to get the getGenericReturnType for the method but it is returning the wrong value.

**1) LongArray.java**

```
package com.test;

public interface LongArray<V> {

     public Iterator<V> iterator();

     interface Iterator<V> {
     }
}
```

**2) Class2.java**

```
package com.test;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class Class2 {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws ClassNotFoundException {

         Class cl = null;
         cl = Class.forName("com.test.LongArray");
         Method[] meths = cl.getDeclaredMethods();
         for (Method m : meths) {            
              Type returnType = m.getGenericReturnType();
              if (returnType != null && returnType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                   ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) returnType;
                   System.out.println("Method Generic Return Type: " +     m.getGenericReturnType().toString());
                   System.out.println();
              }
         }
    }
}
```

## Output

Method Generic Return Type: com.test.LongArray.com.test.LongArray$Iterator

## Javap output

javap LongArray
Warning: Binary file LongArray contains com.test.LongArray
Compiled from "LongArray.java"

```
public interface com.test.LongArray<V> {
    public abstract com.test.LongArray$Iterator<V> iterator();
}
```

According to javap output, it should return "com.test.LongArray$Iterator" but it is returning "com.test.LongArray.com.test.LongArray$Iterator".

Is this a bug in java? Or am i returning the value using wrong api (getGenericReturnType)?

===================================================

I found that, this is a Bug in Java and it is fixed 
See details https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054213

Comment: Looks like you messed up the file system structure. When your classes are in package com.test, then your source files should be in `com/test/`. Otherwise, the compiler might do strange things when it doesn't find the classes.

Comment: All the classes are in the same package. i.e com.test

Comment: It doesn't reproduce for me.. Can you try to do `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cl.getTypeParameters()));` and tell me the output?

Comment: Output is : [V]
I am using java 1.8.
What version you tried?

Comment: I found that, this is a Bug in Java and it is fixed See details https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054213